# Symfony2 - Edit label display name in form

Tags: forms, symfony, label

I need to capitalize the second word in the label name, how do I edit the label name in the form? (e.g., 'Email **A**ddress' and not 'Email **a**ddress')

I've tried setting it in the form creation as follows:

```
->add('Email_Address', 'email', array(
    'attr' => array(
        'label' => 'Email Address',
        'placeholder' => ''
    )
))
```

But this only capitalizes the first letter 'E'mail and not 'A'ddress. I've looked in the `form_div_layout.html.twig` file but didn't see anything to edit this, this probably something simple I'm overlooking.

Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
->add('Email_Address', 'email', array(
    'label' => 'Email Address',
    'attr' => array(
        'placeholder' => '',
    ),
))
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work, move 'label' => '...' before 'attr'.

```
->add('email_address', 'email', array(
    'label' => 'Email Address',
    'attr' => array(
//      'label' => 'Email Address',
        'placeholder' => ''
    )
))
```